# Laravel storage is giving 404 error after storage upload

Tags: laravel, file-upload, laravel-storage

here is my code, how I am uploading to storage and retrieving files. Maybe I am doing it all wrong.

```
$uploadedFileUrl = request()->certificate_template->store('public/certificate');
return url(asset('storage/certificate/'.str_replace('public/certificate/','',$uploadedFileUrl)));
```

Well, I have to upload it to the public/certificate but to get it from storage I have to use storage/certificate. Please help.
Is there any other method I can get files URL from storage files?
Any smarter alternative?

Comment: Execute `php artisan storage:link` for creating symlink. if you are uploaded it to public , then you can access it by `public/certificate/finename.pdf`

Answer (score 0):

For uploading a file to storage use the following code:

```
$file               =       $request->file('attachment');
$file_origname      =       $file->getClientOriginalName();
$file_origext       =       $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
$file_realpath      =       $file->getRealPath();
$file_docsize       =       round(($file->getSize())/1024, 2);
$file_mimetype      =       $file->getMimeType();
$file_giveenname    =       date('YmdHis').Rand().'.'.$file_origext;

$attachment_data = array(
    'original_name'     =>      $file_origname,
    'extension'         =>      $file_origext,
    'path_name'         =>      $file_realpath,
    'size'              =>      $file_docsize,
    'mimetype'          =>      $file_mimetype,
    'file_name'         =>      $file_giveenname
);

Attachments::create($attachment_data);
//---Uploading The File to storage folder
Storage::putFileAs('public/certificate', $file, $file_giveenname);
```

For Accessing the file and viewing the file, first run the following artisan code:

```
php artisan storage:link
```

This artisan command creates an image of your storage folder inside your public folder and it will be easily available and use the following code to access the image in your view.

```
<img src="{{ url('/storage/certificate'.$attachment['file_name']) }}" style="width: 870px; height: 370px;" alt="">
```